# PHP X-User and X-Password authentication

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I am attempting to connect to proofpoint's api.  Their docs state:

"User authentication is carried out by passing a Proofpoint Essentials registered username and password over TLS/SSL. These must be sent in every request in headers:

X-User
  X-Password"

I have tried:

```
$url = "someUrl";
$username = "someUser";
$password = "somePass";

$ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'X-User:'.$username,'X-Password:'.$password));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   $res = json_decode($result);
   print_r($res);
```

I have confirmed username and password are correct but I am getting unauthorized.  Is this the correct format to send this type of auth? I have never seen x-user x-password before.

Comment: What docs are you looking at? The API docs I see on their site say to use standard BASIC auth.

Comment: https://us2.proofpointessentials.com/api/v1/docs/index.php

Comment: I'd leave a space after the colon. Doubt that is the issue but it's what jumped out at first to me.

Comment: According to that doc, your code looks good to me. Only thing I can think is maybe they're being pedantic about formatting and require a space after the colon in each header?

Comment: @ficuscr Heh that bugged me to.

Comment: :) made me go read: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html

Comment: LOL I am on the very same page right now.

Comment: Would i need to encode the password in anyway?  Seems odd to send it in plain-text in the header...

Comment: It's fine in plain text because it's over TLS/SSL. BASIC auth uses BASE64 encoding, so you might try that -- but the docs don't tell you to use it.

Comment: In other scripts I use I have Authorization in the header
'Authorization: Bearer '.$token));
Do I need that at all here?  like 'Authorization: X-User......'    Im just taking stabs in the dark at this point, I appreciate your responses...

Comment: Nope `X-User` should be the full header name, you are doing it correctly according to their docs. What response code are you getting? 401? 403?

Comment: 401. Unauthorized

Comment: You'll have to contact their support to continue debugging. (It seems the only obvious remaining solution is that you have the wrong user or password.)

Comment: Yea that’s what I’m thinking.  This post was mainly to make sure syntax was correct.  I appreciate your time

Comment: Try to encode the values you pass in the URL. Your username and password could stay as it is because they are being sent in the header. Just encode the values and try.

Comment: X-User and X-Password huh... makes you wonder why companies couldn't read the http specification. The authorization header already does this, but we are engineers skilled in the art of reinventing wheels!